# meteor: how to list a collection (the basics)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I really like what I saw with [meteor](https://www.meteor.com). However, I get the impression with the documentation that you need to know the basics. So, something basic like listing a Collections is not described. Anyway, listing a collections is what I want (for now), so could someone help me with that ?

the js file:

```
var Bars = new Meteor.Collection('bar'),

Bars.insert({ title: 'bar', index: 0})
Bars.insert({ title: 'foo', index: 1})

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('bar');

    var list = Bars.find({}).fetch();
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
       // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

the HTML file:

```
<head>
    <title>Meteor test app</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol class="bar">
        {{#each list}}
            <li>{{title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
   </ol>
</body>
```

Simple, but fundamental I thing. Also, would this update if someone else updates the **bar** collection ? Finally, is there a place where this **meteor** magic is explained starting with the basics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the documentation you're looking for is [Template Helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers).

You need to assign the list variable you have to a helper that a template can see.

Something like this:

```
var Bars = new Meteor.Collection('bar');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('bar');

    Template.bars.helpers({
        list: function () {
            return Bars.find({}).fetch();
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Bars.insert({ title: 'bar', index: 0});
    Bars.insert({ title: 'foo', index: 1});
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Meteor test app</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{>bars}}
</body>
<template name="bars">
    <ol class="bar">
        {{#each list}}
            <li>{{title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
</template>
```